glutInit open "Mouse Properties"
I installed freeglut (msys2) and set up glutInit as https://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/initialization/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <GL/freeglut.h>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse3D - GLUT Tutorial");

}

run code: g++ main.cpp -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -o main; main
No error but run code only open Mouse Properties.
a img about Mouse Properties in laptop
I think it only happens in my laptop so I'll provide some information
OS: window 11
Name: MSI thin gf63 12ve
Although I must write something "What did you try and what were you expecting?", I didn't find any information about this error in google. Error in function glutInit, so I can't remove command this bug
